# How to replace eregi()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I tried looking around and thought i figured it out by using `preg_match`, but preg match gives me the error:

Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^'

here is my original code which php says is depreciated:

```
if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_POST['email'])) { 
    $erroR= "Invalid Email address"; 
}
```

can someone explain what the ending delimiter '^' is, and how to add it. thanks@

Comment: Your regex doesn't match many valid email, ie. `my+address@domain.museum`, also domain names could hold accentuated characters like `àéü`...

Comment: im not very good with regex, but i have noticed the `{2,3}` at the end. i wasnt sure what to do. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Replace at least by `{2,6}`. But validate email with regex is a very hard stuff. Have a look at http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap `eregi()` with `preg_match()`, and add delimiters to the regular expression. I chose the standard `/` here, but you can use other characters.

```
if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $_POST['email'])) { 
    $erroR= "Invalid Email address"; 
}
```

The reason you get this warning...

> Warning: `preg_match()`: No ending delimiter `'^'`

...is because `preg_match()` expects delimiters, and it assumed the `^` was being used, and it couldn't match a trailing one.

Comment: that did it, thanks. i didnt even realize the regex wasnt inside slashes.

Comment: Note that `preg_match()` is case sensitive like `ereg()` and there's no case-insensitive variant like `eregi()`.  Instead, you have to specify the appropriate mode modifier.  The most common way to do that is to add `i` after the trailing delimiter: `'/xyz/i'`

Answer (score 1):

Add a `/` before and after your expression - you need a delimiter for `preg_replace` to tell it where the regex starts and finishes. It can be:

```
A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~).
```

So this will work:

```
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/"
```